# 3 panel scrollto window that scrolls left and right but starts in the middle

Tags: jquery, css, scrollto

I'm trying to create an in-page viewer that can scroll through 3 panels starting with the middle panel as the default, allowing the the user to scroll left or scroll right from the middle panel.

I'm using jQuery and scrollTo to switch between the panels, but I can't figure out how to offset the panels so the one in the middle shows by default.  I've tried making the scroll panel container's position relative and setting "right: 500px;".  This positions the middle panel correctly in the viewer, but without using jQuery to clear the position of "right: 500px", the plugin won't scroll to the left-most panel.

Below is the HTML.  I'm hoping I can set the default position of the middle panel using CSS instead of JavaScript?  Is there a way to do that?  Or is there a way to configure scrollTo to set the default position to show the middle panel?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      h1 {
        color: red;
      }
      .list {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        width: 500px;
        float: left;
      }
      .list-canvas {
        position: relative;
        width: 1800px;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .list-canvas .screen {
        width: 500px;
        float: left;
      }
      .green {
        border: 1px solid green;
        background-color: green;
      }
      .red {
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: red;
      }
      .blue {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        background-color: blue;
      }
      .purple {
        border: 3px solid purple;
        background-color: purple;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Testing 3 panel scroll to starting in the middle and being able to scroll-left and scroll-right</h1>
    <br>
    Here is a sample of the 3 panels in their container
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="list-canvas">
      <div class="screen blue">
        I am a summary screen
      </div>
      <div class="screen red">
        I am a list
      </div>
      <div class="screen green">
        I am an info screen
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    Here are the three panes in the viewable area - want to be able to scroll left / right using scrollto but don't know how to figure out how to 
    start in the middle and still have scrollto scroll left when "right" is set to position the list-canvas to show the middle frame.  How do I properly set the offset to make the middle pane the default, and still have scrollto work?
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="list purple">
      <div class="list-canvas" style="right: 500px;">
        <div class="screen blue">
          I am a summary screen
        </div>
        <div class="screen red">
          I am a list
        </div>
        <div class="screen green">
          I am an info screen
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use scrollLeft()

```
$("body").scrollLeft(500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PtzQ8/1/

Comment: Hi Abraham, thanks for the response.  Can't do it on the body tag.  There's more on the page which changing that position would effect.  If .scrollLeft worked when you set the right: 500px style of .list-canvas that would be the way to go like this: $(".list-canvas").scrollLeft(500); but you'll see in the gist here that it doesn't.  It should show the blue box, not the red box in the viewer. http://jsfiddle.net/PtzQ8/2/

Comment: can you add the scrollTo in the jsfiddle to look how it is supposed to work?